# Will it matter if I install an SSD in case location with limited airflow?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, case, case-layout

I am building a new desktop PC using an SSD as the main drive. The case provides a spot in the back of the case (effectively behind the power supply) for mounting an SSD. See attached picture that show the location of the mount. As you can see, since it's behind the backplate, I suspect that there will be considerably less airflow back there, but it will free up one of the drive bays.

Should I be concerned about this? I suspect the airflow won't be any worse than your typical laptop, but will it affect the life of my drive?

[image: SSD mounting location in case]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your SSD will be fine. SSDs are known to consume little power (compared to their magnetic counterparts) and therefore (among other things) do not heat up much. So unless your PS is a radiating heat like a pizza oven it'll be alright.

Answer (score 0):

You should be absolutely fine.  SSDs have no moving parts and run considerably cooler than tradition spinning hard drives.  And in *theory* the case manufacturer would not release a case where hard drives would overheat.